# Problem while reading structure from binary file

Tags: c, sorting, binary, structure

As I was trying to write code which is supposed to sort some structures in a file by a specific field (key), I noticed that my function won't read the key correctly. I don't have any idea what I am doing wrong. The  code is not complete.

The `constr` function is supposed to read one structure at a time from the binary file, then only save the `varsta` array. However, if I try to see what value I obtained, the values are not the ones I gave.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct
{
    char nume[20];
    char prenume[20];
    float varsta;
} PERS;


typedef struct
{
    float key;
    int nr;
}INDEX;

int constr(FILE *f, INDEX tabl[])
{
    int n;
    n = ftell(f) / sizeof(PERS);

    int i, depl = 0;
    PERS p;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fseek(f, depl, 0);

        fread(&p, sizeof(p), 1, f);

        tabl[i].key = p.varsta;
        tabl[i].nr = i;
        depl += sizeof(PERS);

    }

    return n;
}





int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    PERS pers[3];


    if ((f = fopen("fis.txt", "wb+")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not ok");
        exit(1);
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s%s%f", &pers[i].nume, &pers[i].prenume, &pers[i].varsta);
        fwrite(&pers[i], sizeof(PERS), 1, f);

    }


    INDEX tabl[3];

    int n = constr(f, tabl);

    printf("%d", tabl[2].key); //only to check if the key is correct

    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code or looked at the resulting file to be sure you're writing what you think you are?

Comment: At this line : `tabl[i].key = p.varsta;`: varsta is a float, but key is an int. Is this intended?

Comment: No, just a mistake. I made the change, but its not the problem

Comment: the `fseek` isn't needed - the position in the file will increase the right amount every time you call `fread`

Comment: i just corrected the "wb". However, the result i get when i try to display the key is "-nan". I dont know what this means

Comment: Your code reads text, not binary.

Comment: @stark why is that ?

Comment: In a binary file, strings are null-terminated and floats are in bytes, not characters.

Comment: @stark the fread and fwrite are directly applied to a _PERS_, it is binary. The scanf is from stdin

Comment: My mistake. I was looking at the scanf

Comment: @MaryPoppins you write and read well the file, you just printf wrongly the key because of the format %d rather than  %f or equivalent. So all is good ... except the test to check if it is good :-)

Comment: @bruno all this trouble for nothing, haha. Thank you all

Answer (score 3):

The `key` field is a float, but you are trying to print an integer.

Change the penultimate line in your code to

```
printf("%.2f\n", tabl[2].key);
```

Comment: @MaryPoppins: It works for me after making the afore-mentioned change. If you have changed your code please ensure your answer contains the exact code you are currently using. Also: try examine the file using `hexedit` or similar program.